# Apply Filter For All Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I would like to have freeze pane in all new excel files. In which template do I need apply this? I am using Office 2016

Appreciate any insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heading says apply filter but the question is about freezing the pane. I will answer for freezing the pane. Just save the excel file as a template. You can do that usng "Save as" option and selecting either "save as excel template" or "save as excel template with macro" (in case you have macros too).

By doing this every new workbook created out of the template(when you double-click the template excel file) will have the panes froze on the column or row.

Comment: Thanks Sreejith for the answer. I do have an application or a tool named as TOAD (for Oracle) where data can be exported to excel. In this tool, excel is opened as soon as I mention excel is the output format. So saving an excel as a template would not help.

Comment: Toad like apps use "automation" to "invoke" the excel application and make it do few tasks. It is definitely possible for such apps to automate it beyond like adding filters, pivot tables , data connections etc. This is however based on "limits" that the developers have put on the tool. So when I search about Toad this is all I get https://www.toadworld.com/products/toad-data-point/f/36/t/32206

Comment: @Sreejith.D.Menon ,, you have suggested Save the File as Template and Double Click will Freeze the Pane,, !! How this is possible?

Comment: Rajesh S - Did you try this? What did you try?

Comment: Exactly the same you have suggested,,,,,,!

Comment: So you open a new workbook, Save that as excel template and make your changes, which, here the user wanted is "freeze panes". Save the work and then spawn a new workbook out of the template - you dont see the panes frozen?. Then you are not trying exactly what I have said. Sorry you should try again.